# Component does not receive props from getStaticProps when wrapped with HOC

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, higher-order-components

Can anyone help me with a thecnical question about next SSR and private routes?
I have a page that use `getStaticProps` to be mounted by SSR and want to guarantee that only authorized users access then.

I tried `getServerSideProps`, but I can't use `getServerSideProps` with `getStaticProps`.

I also tried some HOCs implementations, but my page does not execute `getStaticProps` when it's wrapped by auth HOC component.

**EDIT:**
Page called `getStaticProps` but don't receive updated data by `getStaticProps`. Only undefined on props.

My `getStaticProps`

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async context => {
  const { slug } = context.params;

  const response = await api.get<ICourse>(`course/${slug}`);
  const course = response.data;
  return {
    props: {
      course,
    },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
};

export default privateRoute(Course);
```

My HOC

```js
function redirectToHome() {
  router.replace('/');
}
function privateRoute(WrappedComponent: any) {
  return class extends Component<AuthProps> {
    state: { isLoading: boolean };

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }
    async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
      if (!cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN_COOKIE)) {
        redirectToHome();
      }
      try {
        const user = await AuthService.getUser();
        if (user?._id) {
          const permit = await permissionService.get(user._id);
          if (!permit) {
            redirectToHome();
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        redirectToHome();
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { isLoading } = this.state;
      return (
        <div>{isLoading ? <>Check permission</> : <WrappedComponent />}</div>
      );
    }
  };
}
export default privateRoute;
```

Comment: Are you certain `getStaticProps` doesn't get called with the HOC? Do you get any errors?

Comment: it's called, but don't inject staticprops on page. my page only receive undefined by props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the props from your HOC down to the `<WrappedComponent />`.

```js
render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? <>Check permission</> : <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />}
        </div>
    );
}
```